# Facebook share functionality is not working in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8, sharing, ios8.1

I have implemented Facebook sharing functionality using social framework. I have configured the Facebook account using device setting. When I installed the Facebook app on device, sharing is not working as expected.

When share window appears, it only has the image for sharing and no initial text and URL.

iOS8 - Share functionality is working properly if I remove the Facebook app from device.

iOS7 - Share functionality is working properly even the Facebook app is on device.

I am not sure where it is a framework issue or something is missing?

```
SLComposeViewController *facebookShareVC = [SLComposeViewController  composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_%@_%@.gif", [[STInteractionManager sharedManager] getAppLibraryCacheDirectory], article.journalID, article.volume, article.issueNumber];

UIImage* img = [[STInteractionManager sharedManager] imageNamedFromDocuments:imagePath];

[facebookShareVC setInitialText:self.articleTitle];

[facebookShareVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.url   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?dispform=ios-device" withString:@""]]];

[facebookShareVC addImage:img];

[self presentViewController:facebookShareVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is a known issue.

Comment: It's by design. According to Facebook Platform Policy, you can't pre-fill using iOS share sheet. See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill. Relevant discussion: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-fill the fields, you shouldn't use the Facebook SDK at all. Instead, use the Social framework provided by Apple. With only a few lines of code, you can trigger the SLComposeViewController.

Comment: I am aware of UIActivityViewController for sharing the article.
SLComposeViewController is not a Facebook SDK. It a made available by Apple to do sharing on Facebook and Twitter. I had a different requirement at that time(before 2 years).